# Having trouble with Marionette JS router

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette, backbone-routing

I am having a trouble with my router and controller.  On my app's `before:start`, I have a handler that fetches collections of Leads and Vehicles.

I have a single region, with my layout view as:

```
var App = new Marionette.Application({});

var AppLayoutView = Marionette.LayoutView.extend({
  el: 'body',
  regions: {
    main: '#app-container'
  }
});
```

My controller is:

```
var Controller = Marionette.Object.extend({
    leads: function() {
      App.regions.main.show(new App.leadsTableView({collection: App.leads}));
    },
    vehicles: function() {
      App.regions.main.show(new App.vehiclesTableView({collection: App.vehicles}));
    }
});
```

In my start handler:

```
App.on('start', function() {
  App.regions = new AppLayoutView();
  App.router = new Marionette.AppRouter({
    controller: new Controller(),
    appRoutes: {
      'leads': 'leads',
      'vehicles': 'vehicles'
    }
  });

  Backbone.history.start({pushState: true});
});

App.start();
```

How can I start with a specific route?  And, when a user goes to #vehicles, how can I make the region load the new view?  I'm missing something about routers.

EDIT: When I go to, #leads in my URL, my vehicles view comes up.  When I click on links that go to #leads and #vehicles, they don't work.

Comment: Can you describe more specific about the result when you run this code ? This code can render the view to the region? maybe you can paste the code to jsfiddle to make others know more.

Comment: When I click on a link, it goes to #vehicles or #leads, but doesn't call any handler.  Nothing happens.  Then I click on the URL with #leads, the URL goes to /leads, but the vehicles view displays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Default route

You can define a default by adding a "splat" route (one that starts with `*`) to the end of your routes. I like to use `*default` to make the intent obvious:

```
appRoutes: {
  'leads': 'leads',
  'vehicles': 'vehicles',
  '*default': 'leads'
}
```

#### Broken links

Because you are using `pushstate` routing, the view URL is `/vehicles` rather than the hash fragment `#vehicles`. You should no longer use hash fragment urls.

Here's a simple approach to trigger pushState routes with link clicks:

```
$('a[href]').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var href = e.target.getAttribute('href');
  App.router.navigate(href, { trigger: true })
});
```

You may find this [post about moving from hash fragment to pushState routing](http://artsy.github.io/blog/2012/06/25/replacing-hashbang-routes-with-pushstate/) useful.

You'll also need to configure your server to pass requests that match your route to the main app page - for example, it needs to understand that `http://localhost/app/vehicle` should be handled by `http://localhost/app`.

Comment: I added that splat route, and it now goes to the right controller.  So, my only issue is my links don't work.  Nothing executes from a nav link.

Comment: @vintorg you need to use "real" URLs rather than hash fragments. Please see the updated answer.